# VARCHAR vs LONGTEXT for synopsis

Tags: mysql

I have a collection of synopses that are about 1000 char long each. In MySQL, should I store these as `VARCHAR` or as `LONGTEXT`. Why? And what is the main difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`varchar` datatype is the far more appropriate datatype for dealing with such short notes.VARCHAR is actually part of the ISO standard; The `TEXT` data types, including `LONGTEXT`, are non-standard.

Keep in mind that that the number in `VARCHAR(x)` represents number of characters, not number of bytes. Therefore, you may have difficulties trying to define a table with only VARCHAR(65532) if the character set uses multi-byte characters, such as UTF-8.

There are limitations if attributes of `text` datatype be compared, sorted, manipulated with string functions etc.